# REST Stream's OutgoingResponse.ContentType is ignored, always shows "application/xml" on receiving browser

Tags: wcf, stream, content-type, webhttpbinding, self-hosting

I have a self-hosted WCF REST/`webHttpBinding`-endpoint-bound service.  I have a few streams of different content types that it serves.  The content itself is delivered correctly, but any `OutgoingResponse.ContentType` setting seems to be ignored and instead delivered as `"application/xml"` every time.

Browsers seems to *get over it* for javascript and html (depending on how it's to be consumed), but not for css files which are interpreted more strictly.  CSS files are how I realized the problem but it's a problem for all Streams.  Chromebug and IE developer tools both show `"application/xml"` regardless of what I put in the serving code for a content type.  I've also tried setting the content type header as a `Header` in `OutgoingResponse` but that makes no difference and it probably just a long way of doing what OutgoingResponse.ContentType does already.

```
[OperationBehavior]
System.IO.Stream IContentChannel.Code_js()
{
    WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "text/javascript;charset=utf-8";

    var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();

    using (var sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(ms, Encoding.UTF8, 512, true))
    {
        sw.Write(Resources.code_js);
        sw.Flush();
    }

    ms.Position = 0;

    return ms;
}
```

This behavior is added:

```
var whb = new WebHttpBehavior
{
    DefaultBodyStyle = System.ServiceModel.Web.WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
    DefaultOutgoingRequestFormat = System.ServiceModel.Web.WebMessageFormat.Json,
    DefaultOutgoingResponseFormat = System.ServiceModel.Web.WebMessageFormat.Json,
    HelpEnabled = false
};
```

I've tried setting `AutomaticFormatSelectionEnabled = true` and `false` just in case because it came up in google searches on this issue, but that has no effect on this.

I'm finding enough [articles](http://www.code-magazine.com/Article.aspx?quickid=080014) that show Stream and ContentType working together to confuse the heck out of me as to why this isn't working.  I believe that the `Stream` is only intended to be the body of the response, not the entire envelope.

My .svclog doesn't show anything interesting/relevant that I recognize.

============

I can confirm in Fiddler2 that the headers are being delivered as shown in the browser.

```
...
Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

I had something like the following in a MessageInspector:

HttpResponseMessageProperty responseProperty = new HttpResponseMessageProperty();
responseProperty.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
reply.Properties["httpResponse"] = responseProperty;

and this was overwriting the already-present HttpResponseMessageProperty in reply.Properties, including any contentType settings.  Instead, I tryget the HttpResponseMessageProperty first and use the existing one if found.

I lucked out seeing that one.